# File access android

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm making a hand-outs app for android or like a book reader for android.

I have a parsed xml stream uploaded online and my app will parse the data in the said xml file with links inside it to be downloaded. It will be saved in the sdcard with a specific extension name that only my app can read and should be encrypted.

I managed to encrypt and decrypt the file, but I like something like when I open the file manager and locate the file, clicked the file it will open my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading these:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

[Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

Comment: is there a full project sample you know or can give? kinda lost here, thanks.

Comment: Maybe this discussion makes your mind more clear:  
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/a7qsSl3vQq0

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to save the files with a custom extension and associate your app with that extention.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806807/associate-file-type-with-android-app-fails) post might guide you