# Opening specific file extension in Android not working with intent filter

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want my app to show in the opening options when clicking on a specific file extension. I tried the following code from another stack overflow question but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? The app doesn't show up in the list of options.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">

        <intent-filter
            android:label="Application"
            android:priority="1"
            >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4149926/115145

Comment: Well actually I do not want to open pdfs, but a custom file extension, sorry!

Comment: Android does not support custom file extensions very well.

Comment: I don't understand why the path pattern doesn't work.

Comment: You are unlikely to be getting a `file` `Uri`, as that was largely banned with Android 7.0 several years ago. The more likely situation is a `content` `Uri`, and those do not use file extensions all the time, just like Web URLs do not use file extensions all the time.